# Contract not showing the name and symbol

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, remix, ropsten, openzeppelin

I deployed a contract on ropsten but it was not showing the name and the symbol. I have the feeling that there is something wrong at the deployment and I think it has to do with the parameters. As you can see in the picture.... is it the way I should write them or is it wrong  ? Thank you very much

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The parameters are not *wrong*, there's no error during deployment and the compiler is acting as expected.

In Solidity, when you declare a variable as `public`, you are telling the compiler to create a public function with the same name of the variable, so that you can query the value of the variable from outside the smart contract.

In your case, you are declaring your variables as `private`, so the compiler does not create those functions.

Just change the visibility of `name` and `symbol` variables from `private` to `public` and you will be able to read those values easily from remix or any other ÐApp.

**Note**: please always post the source code exposing the problem, not a snaphost of it.